# MVC Core 3.1 with Hosted Services on Quartz scheduled every 1 hour dont start

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

Dears, I have a mvc core 3.1 app running under IIS with as mentioned in title "Hosted Service" which should be executed every 1 hour. It actually does execute if website wasn't idle for some time.. Is it possible to tell app to don't go to sleep? :)

Comment: Is it a requirement to host in IIS? if not host it in a windows service or kestral then you dont have this problem

Comment: unfortunetly it must be in IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set always running application in iis you could try below setting:

1)Open iis manager

2)Select the application pool of your site.

3)The select advance setting from the action pane.

4)set start mode always running and ideal time out 0.

[image]

5)Under Recycling, set the Regular Time Interval (minutes) to 0.

[image]

Select Specific Times and either click the > expander arrow to see if there is time specified below or click the ... to see if there are any values in the TimeSpan Collection Editor dialog. If so, clear it out.

[image]